# loading simple iframe from extension firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created a webpage that runs a script that I would like to be able to open from a button on the Firefox taskbar like an extension. If this looks something like [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/two-factor-authenticator/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) layout wise that would be fine. I was hoping to open an iframe in which the page is loaded. Does an extension exist for this or is it possible to create this for personal use myself?

I'm completely new at building Firefox extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be pretty simple. You basically create a file like [this](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/tabs-tabs-tabs/manifest.json) and add it to the [addons website](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/distribute-sideloading/) which can be set to personal or public use. Done.